# connecting to access database and query user login information not pulling data back

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

any help would be great thank you. not sure why its all ways returning a null
I'm not sure if its even connecting to the database.

my web config file

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="accessConnectionString" providerName="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\***\Desktop\pratice\AccessTest\App_Data\TheList.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

middle tier code to check if user is in the database if they are return something if not return null

```
OleDbConnection sconn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand scmd = new OleDbCommand();
    public DBMiddleTier()
    {
        try
        {
            // set up the connection strings        
            sconn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["accessConnectionString"].ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }//end of constructor
    //class to check membership
    public object checkMembership(string logid, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            sconn.Open();
            //set propertiers of the command
            scmd.Connection = sconn;
            scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            scmd.CommandText = "select * from SubDealers where LoginID = @InputUsername and Password = @InputPassword";
            scmd.Parameters.Clear();
            OleDbParameter checkUsername = scmd.Parameters.Add("@InputUsername", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
            checkUsername.Value = logid;
            OleDbParameter checkPassword = scmd.Parameters.Add("@InputPassword", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
            checkPassword.Value = password;
            object result = scmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return result;
        }
        catch (OleDbException sqx)
        {
            throw sqx;
        }
        finally
        {
            sconn.Close();
        }
    }//end of method
```

my code behind page

```
try
        {
            object result = dm.checkMembership(txtLoginID.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            if (result != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
            }
            else
            {
                txtLoginID.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "notAmember", "alert('Sorry wrong id or password');", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
        }
```

Comment: can't you step through the code and check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
select * from [SubDealers] where [LoginID] = @InputUsername and [Password] = @InputPassword"
```